API Platform - customize error pages on prod
In my Symfony application, I would like to customize 500 Internal Error messages to direct the user to call them on some action instead of the generic 500 that Symfony displays on PROD env.
Meaning that I would like to overwrite twig and display some custom info I prefer.
Reference link: https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/controller/error_pages.html#use-default-error-controller
I am not sure that this is achievable within the API Platform that I am using.
Reference: https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.6/core/errors/
Checking its documentation, it does not have any information regarding this specific question.
If someone can help regarding this, I would be grateful..
Thanks
